# constructors and compilation

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

Two things:

1. This is a section of a program that I wrote, but it is not running.
2. Generally, the mission that I got includes defining 2 constructors, and I do not understand how it is possible to a class to work with 2 constructors, logically.
   I think I managed to create the basic constructor, but I do not know how to create it (and why?).

The 2nd constructor (the constructor that is displayed in the code between /* and */) needs to receive another time and to copy its values.

Thanks for any help!

==================================================================================

```
public class Time1 {

private int _hour,
            _minute,
            _second;

public Time1 (int h, int m, int s) {
    if (hourIsValid (h))
        _hour = h;
    else _hour = 0;

    if (minuteIsValid (m))
        _minute = m;
    else minute = 0;

    if (secondIsValid (s))
        _second = s;
    else _second = 0;
}

boolean hourIsValid (h) {
    return (h <= 23 && h >= 0);
}

boolean minuteIsValid (m) {
    return (m <= 59 && m >= 0);
}

boolean secondIsValid (s) {
    return (s <= 59 && s >= 0);
}

/*  public Time1 (Time1 other) {...




}
*/

int getHour() {
    return _hour;
}

int getMinute() {
    return _minute;
}

int getSecond() {
    return _second;
}

void setHour (int num) {
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 23)
        _hour = num;
}

void setMinute (int num) {
    if (num >= 0 && num <=59)
        _minute = num;
}

void setSecond (int num) {
    if (num >= 0 && num <=59)
        _second = num;
}

String toString () {
    String strH,
           strM,
           strS;
    if (_hour < 10)
        strH = "0" + _hour + ":";
    else strH = _hour + ":";

    if (_minute < 10)
        strM = "0" + _minute + ":";
    else strM = _minute + ":";

    if (_second < 10)
        strS = "0" + _second;
    else strS = _second;

    return (strH + strM + strS);
}
    /*if (_hour < 10)
        System.out.print("0" + _hour + ":");
    else System.out.print(_hour + ":");

    if (_minute < 10)
        System.out.print("0" + _minute + ":");
    else System.out.print(_minute + ":");

    if (_second < 10)
        System.out.print("0" + _second);
    else System.out.print(_second); 
}
*/

 boolean equals (Time1 other) {
     return ((_hour == other._hour) && (_minute == other._minute) && (_second == other._second));
 }

 boolean before (Time1 other) {
     return ((_hour < other._hour) || 
             ((_hour == other._hour) && (_minute < other._minute)) || 
             ((_hour == other._hour) && (_minute == other._minute) && (_second < other._second)));
 }

 boolean after (Time1 other) {
     return other.before(this);
 }

 int difference (Time1 other) {
     int obSec, otherSec;

     obSec = ((_hour * 60 * 60) + (_minute * 60) + _second);
     otherSec = ( (other._hour * 60 * 60) + (other._minute * 60) + other._second);

     return (obSec - otherSec);
 }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you're new to java and programming in general? Have you read anything about classes/constructors/methods and so on? Anyway; multiple constructors are explained on many places on the internet, so a simple google search will probably do the trick... http://beginwithjava.blogspot.se/2010/08/multiple-constructor-methods.html

Answer (score 3):

It's called overloading. You can define methods with the same name as long as they have different parameters, but share return type (or return void, or in the case of constructors, lack return type). The compiler will know what method to use based on the parameters used to call it.

In this case I'd guess what you want is something like:

```
public Time1 (Time1 other) {
  this._hour = other.getHour();
  this._minute = other.getMinute();
  this._second = other.getSecond();
}
```

Another option would be to chain the constructors by using the `this` keyword like this:

```
public Time1 (Time1 other) {
  this(other.getHour(), other.getMinute(), other.getSecond());
}
```

As you want to copy the variables from the Time1-object you pass to the constructor. Of course you should add error checking etcetera, but I hope you get the general idea.

Oracle have some decent [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) that you might want to look into.

Comment: +1 IMO nice explained. Your tutorials are fine, but I suggest that OP use quick info here [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Overloading_Methods_and_Constructors].

Comment: @BoskoMijin Good link. I just default to Oracle when it comes to Java and forget that there are other, possibly better stuff around :)

Comment: if i understood it correctly, you use the 2nd constructor only after you used the basic one?

Comment: @user3403740 No, the constructors are independent, and which one will be executed depends on the arguments you pass when you create the object. You can chain constructor calls though, so if you have a constructor that takes three parameters, that one can call a constructor taking two parameters and so forth; this can be done to minimized code duplication. In your case, if you create a new Time1 object by passing another Time1 object to the constructor the only constructor that will be executed is the one taking a Time1 object as argument.